# VS Code "C#" Extension Popups?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

How to prevent all these popups?

[image]

Comment: The errors only indicated the extension had difficulty reaching to the C# language server behind the scene. But it is impossible to tell more without accessing this machine. You cannot prevent them without fixing the language server connection either, because without it that extension loses functionalities.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=github+vscode+csharp+%22request+textdocument%22+%22failed%22 we'd need more detail to narrow down what issue you're having. provide more info about how to reproduce this.